# Inspiration / convention for element names HTML

Tags: html, css, templating

I work in front end markup so I'm constantly templating site. Does anyone know of good resources to learn some good conventions or inspiration for element names? I like names that relate to print layouts so perhaps someone could point me to a resource for naming different sections of a document/layout.

I get a bit sick of using generic names such as `block, wrapper, content, header` etc over and over. Things like `colophon, masthead, hero` etc seem to hold more meaning.

Comment: Do you mean adding id attributes to the elements? I tend to use id's sparingly, mostly only as anchor points within a page. If then I usually give it an id that semantically describes the are of the page I am anchoring to.

Comment: You're really looking for an approach which more or less matches your own syntactical understanding. I can't see how there's a "real" answer here (that isn't just a link to some off-site explanation). Maybe I'm wrong. Review templates, source markup and other possibly "professionally" designed templates and come up with your own system. Share on a blog entry, try to attract professionals to your approach, and see who agrees/bickers.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the idea. If someone can post an answer with a link to a blog post or forum on the matter i'll accept it

Comment: The answers are useful in their own way, but as I frame this question for myself, I'm looking for a more granular naming convention that I can apply to generic page components to be composed in our inhouse SMACSS framework (Scalable and Modular Architecture for CSS: an attempt to document a consistent approach to site development when using CSS).  I've been looking to print terminology for answers, but haven't found a great resource. Great question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A little bit of inspiration**

I remember finding [this](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/naming_conventions_table.html) when I was searching for the same thing. It's a collection of names used by some of the best known css guys. It comes from [Andy Clarke](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/)

Comment: Stuff like this is great! Thank you, if anyone else has similar lists please share as I think other people would find them useful

Comment: +1 for introducing the terms "ashtray" and "humidor" to my future style sheets

Answer (score 0):

Here you go as requested in your comment...

http://meiert.com/en/blog/20080812/best-practice-ids-and-classes/

Got this in 10 seconds by typing 'best practice html class names' into Google.

Personally, I name my elements as abbreviations of what they relate to - div containing a submit button I would name 'smtbtn'. Short, sweet and phonetically almost says what it is.